# Request to merge tags: datacenter and [data-center]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please merge these tags:

- [datacenter](https://serverfault.com/tags/datacenter)
- [data-center](https://serverfault.com/tags/data-center)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

I feel dirty because the One True Spelling is datecentre, but I think I can live with this one.

Comment: You can merge that also! And 'colo' and 'colocation'!

Comment: Well, datacentre doesn't exist, nobody has used it ;) Same goes for colo/colocation, nobody has used the colo tag yet

Comment: Can a tag synonym exist before a tag is instantiated?

Comment: @jscott No, but that's easy to fix.